# Is it better to extend store as object or service in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

In ember why is it more advantageous to write a store as an extension of service rather than an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a service.

On the surface, the difference between `Ember.Object` and `Ember.Service` is superficial: a boolean `isServiceFactory` which you could set yourself.

Besides the niceties that ember-cli and the ember resolver give you when using services (injections, lazy evaluation, etc.), the only real difference is how you look at these things mentally.

An object is generic, and says nothing about it's purpose.  A service is less generic. By calling something a service you are telling yourself and other programmers that "this thing has long-lived state that is shared across the app".  Specifically, you are saying that the state of this thing lasts for the entirety of the app's life-cycle once instantiated, and is utilized by routes/controllers/components on more than one of your routes.

It's a mental construct, more than a physical one, but it helps you and others conceptualize the app's organization better.

Answer (score 0):

`Ember.Service` is easily injectable into controllers, routes, components, mixins, other services. It is lazily evaluated, so only if you will call this service, for example, via `this.get('store')` it will load store service. It is encouraged pattern to use services instead of globals, or injecting javascript objects at lower level.